# Consolidate rows for sending to an email based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

what's up! Currently, I have a working code that allows the sending of emails from google sheets if the *"Reminder date"* is today or before, and *"Done"* checkbox is unticked.

Currently, I use a `TEXTJOIN` function to consolidate tasks that are for sending and with the same recipient. When I run my code, it doesn't list the items in bullets, but on a single line. I'm not sure how to rewrite the "message" part so that it bullets these textjoin'ed values.

Here is the current code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var now = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Tasks')
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[2];       
    var ReminderDate = row[3].toLocaleDateString();
    var Status = row[5];
    var subject = "Task reminders";

    if (ReminderDate > now)
      continue;

    if (Status != true) {  
      var Email = {
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: "Task reminders  |  "+now,
        htmlBody:
        "Good day! This is to remind you of the following specific task/s:"+
        "<br />"+
        "<ul><li>"+message+"</li></ul>"+
        "<br /><br />"+
        "You can access the Task monitoring sheet by clicking <a href=" + ss.getUrl() + ">here</a>.",
        name: "Taks monitoring",
      };
      MailApp.sendEmail(Email);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(now);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
     }
    }
```

**Here's the Google sheet:**

[image]

**Here is what I'm receiving:**

[image]

**But here's what I really want:**

[image]

I tried googling several samples, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, as to why I don't seem to be finding any similar case. I hope I could get guidance here though on what to understand and learn to achieve the goal. I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do on how the code reads the `message`, or perhaps should I not `TEXTJOIN` anymore - just capture the individual rows that are for sending to the same person, and combine them via the code *(also not sure how to do that or if that's even possible)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes that there is an in-cell line break between the list items.

After this line:

```
var message = row[2];
```

Add this line

```
  message = message.replace(/\n/g, "</li><li>");
```

It will replace the line-breaks with HTML tags.

Comment: I think that your approach is better. I could study from your answer. Thank you so much. I would like to upvote this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @ADW! :)

Answer (score 1):

- In your situation, the line breaks in a cell in the Spreadsheet are not reflected to the email.
- You want to reflect the line breaks to the email.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In your situation, `message` is used as HTML data. So how about modifying as follows? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### From:

```
var message = row[2];
```

#### To:

```
var message = row[2].split("\n").reduce(function(s, e) {return s += "<li>" + e + "</li>"}, "");
```

And

#### From:

```
"<ul><li>"+message+"</li></ul>"+
```

#### To:

```
"<ul>" + message + "</ul>" +
```

#### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Wouldn't adding `<ul>` tags to every array item create 3 separate lists in this case?

Comment: @ross Yes. Thank you for your support. I had used the older version. I updated it just now. Could you please confirm it?